# Syntax error on line containing if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I keep trying to make a simple guess the number game but Python keeps saying my code has a syntax error. What am I doing wrong?

```
import random
takeone = input("Guess A Number Between 1 & 5")
numberinit = random.randint(1,5)
if "takeone" == "numberinit"
    print("Your Right")
else:
    print("Your Wrong")
```

Comment: python basics... `if <condition> :`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax error you're getting is probably something like the following:

```
  File "test.py", line 4
    if "takeone" == "numberinit"
                               ^    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This means you're missing a colon at the end of the `if` line. The line should instead read:

```py
if "takeone" == "numberinit":
```

Comment: @tourniquet_grab Thanks! Stupid mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Documentation on the Python `if` statement can be found at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html.

Here's a correct example:

```
import random
takeone = input("Guess A Number Between 1 & 5")
numberinit = random.randint(1,5)
if "takeone" == "numberinit":
    print("Your Right")
else:
    print("Your Wrong")
```